# Need to load multiple sql server tables from C# app

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xsd

Hi I have a pretty complex schema (.xsd) and an .xml files.  Some nodes have about 70 attributes and some 10-15.  I used xsd2code to create c# classes and then deserialized my xml file.  I created a database based on my .xsd class using xsd2db application.  So I've read my xml file and need to store it into the database.  I have 74 classes/tables with primary/foreign key relationships.  I looked into SqlBulkCopy - for that it looks like I need to convert everything into datatables/rows/columns. And I will need to take into account the hierarchy for satisfying foreign keys. Is there another way of doing it?  What would be the best (fastest) approach?
Thank you
Jenny

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to import a XML file either through T-SQL, SSIS, VB Script, etc.

Sorry to just google and post links, but I think sql squirrel has found the easiest method for getting an XML file into SQL Server 2005 is to use T-SQL:

http://www.lockergnome.com/sqlsquirrel/2008/05/22/how-to-import-a-xml-file-into-sql-server-2005/

http://www.lockergnome.com/sqlsquirrel/2008/05/23/how-to-turn-imported-xml-into-a-relational-format-in-sql-server-2005/

The SQLTeam seem to think T-SQL is the WTG as well:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/06/18/60235.aspx

Comment: Thank you Jeremy.  I tried SSIS.  First I thought it would be the best way of doing it.  If I can't figure out the other way, I'll go with SSIS.  But it required my db and xml files to be on the same server and almost all the data types didn't match so I need to convert data types for 15-70 columns in each of 74 tables.  I found

Comment: I found SQLXML Bulk Load - which seems like a great solution too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171878.aspx except that I don't have  Microsoft SQLXML Bulkload 4.0 Type Library (xblkld4.dll) - and it needs to be installed separately (SQLXML enables XML support for SQL Server Database) and it's not an option for me.

Comment: @Boroda Here is a post to help you find SQLXML (xblkld4.dll) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlxml/thread/f974763f-b189-456d-8b9a-6100d46cae15. SQLXML Bulkload looks way over the top for importing XML files especially if its once off: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171806.aspx. I'd personally prefer to use a combination of FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ‘ ‘ ‘ + @xmlFileName + ‘ ‘ ‘ , SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA and massage the data using SQL, LINQ-to-XML and SQLSMO (sql mgt objects). Is this a once off operation? and what version of SQL server do you have?